# Running scraping script on AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am scraping data from the internet and would like to do it automatically with AWS. I checked two solutions: AWS Data Pipeline and AWS Lambda.

Data Pipeline seems not to be able to access online websites. Is it correct?

AWS Lambda allows running my function only for 15 mins, whereas my scraping takes around 25 mins. Which again, it doesnt suit my purpose.

Which AWS service should I use for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

You could launch an Amazon EC2 instance. You can pass a startup script via the User Data field, which will execute when the instance first starts.

Then, when the task is finished, either Stop or terminate the Instance.

Note that the [Amazon EC2 Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) you select will have varying network bandwidth, which may impact the speed of the scraping task.

Please always respect the Terms and Conditions of your target website(s) so that your scraping activity does not violate their terms.